# Use populate() for two different schemas in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two MongoDB collections - comments

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  body: String,
  author: String,
  upvotes: {type: Number, default: 0},
  post: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Profile' }
});

mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

and users

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userName: String,
  userJobRole: String,
  userEmail: String,
  userPhone: String,
  userTimeZone: String,
  post: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Profile' }
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

I want to use populate for each of these schemas in my get request. One for users and one for comments from these models.

```
router.get('/profiles/:profile', function(req, res, next) {
  req.post.populate('users', function(err, post) {
    if(err) { return next(err) }
    res.json(post);
  });
});
```

I can only figure out how to call one.

Does Mongoose allow you to populate from two schemas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to populate multiple paths, you can pass a space delimited string of path names to the populate method on any document as follows:

```
Story
.find(...)
.populate('fans _creator') // space delimited path names
.exec()
```

This is taken directly from the Mongoose docs http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Thanks. router.get('/profiles/:profile', function(req, res, next) {
  req.post.populate('users comments', function(err, post) {
    if(err) { return next(err) }
    res.json(post);
  });
}); did the trick